# NotSerializableException on LinearLayout after open pdf reader

Tags: android

I'm facing a problem and I don't know how to solve it.
After my app open a pdf reader, I have this crash log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.nicopasso.views.Box)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1394)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1341)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:644)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1034)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:669)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:136)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1197)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:381)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1363)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1268)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:644)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1034)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:669)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2919)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3296)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.widget.LinearLayout
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
        at 
....
....
```

The problem seems to be in LinearLayout (my Box class extends LinearLayout) which does not implement the Serializable interface.

The Box class:

```
 public class Box extends LinearLayout implements BoxInterface, Serializable {
    private transient Context mContext;
    public Box(Integer boxId, Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        init(boxId);
    }

    private void init(Integer boxId) {
        View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.box, this);

        mBoxId = boxId;

   }
   //other stuff...
}
```

Is there a way to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Bundle the view state you need on the other  side and reconstruct it

Comment: Could you explain me how to do this with code?

Answer (score 1):

Does your class keep a reference to a LinearLayout or some other view that contains a LinearLayout in the view hierarchy?

When your activity goes to the background, the operating system tries to serialize your activity's member variables in order to store them in a Bundle, so when it comes back to the foreground you can regenerate it's existing state.

However somewhere you're keeping a reference to a LinearLayout (or a view with a LinearLayout) which doesn't implement Serializable, so you're getting this exception.

Comment: Nice hypothesis.

Comment: I found this question because I was getting the same exception, and that's what was causing my problem :)

Comment: Is any one got solution of this exception.